# Finding open paths in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, path

I uploaded a file to a market place but it got rejected. They sent me messages for some modifications and the one modification they want is to close opened paths.

How can I find open paths or their numbers? i.e. how many paths are opened

I am using Adobe Illustrator CS6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select all objects <kbd>Command/Control+A</kbd>,

Press Window and Choose Document Info

[image]

Choose Object in drop-down menu

[image]

Check open paths:

[image]

Comment: @user there are a lot of ways to find open paths, i.e. every time you choose the path or layer this panel will show how many open path there are, secondly you can just see that, you can switch to outline mode or use some script...

Comment: @user The main goal of the topic starter - not to be rejected by Stock company manager. The only way to be 100% sure he has no open paths - is by the answer provided, because if he has path consisted of 1 point point he can miss it with any other method (especially if it outside the artboard or just below any visible path. Additionally, only by this method one can get the answer from the system.

Comment: @user Dominic, you should ask others, not me

Comment: Of course this only shows **if** there are open paths. You'd have to select each path individually to find an open path.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this on Adobe CC 2018?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **Illustrator CS6 or *earlier*** you can use [Rick Johnson's Select Menu Plug in](http://rj-graffix.com/wordpress/software/plugins/#selectmenu).

Mr. Johnson has not updated the plug in any version newer than CS6, unfortunately. However, if you are using CS6 or older, it's a very handy plug in  to have. And it's *free*.

Comment: I know this plugin but can't use it. I am using Adobe Illustrator CS6.

Comment: I figured that. However, it still worth providing for users who are tied to legacy versions of the application.

Comment: Just for future visitors, it appears the plugin was updated for CS6.

Comment: The [Select Menu plugin is available at this new URL](https://rj-graffix.com/downloads/plugins/#selectmenu), is now compatible with versions of Adobe Illustrator from 3 to CC2020, and is still free.

Answer (score 5):

My method:

1. Create a pattern brush using grey for the inner sections, but with bright red end caps for the beginning and end sections.
2. Apply the brush to the artwork to identify the open paths.
3. Undo the apply, then fix the path.

Comment: Good idea to use a brush! Arrowheads may be easier and accomplish the same thing essentially.

Comment: Unfortunately, stroke arrowheads show up whether the path is closed or not.

Answer (score 3):

To find and close your opened paths you can:
- switch to `outline mode` Ctrl+Y
- look over your paths and find (visually) ones not closed
- select opened path and press Ctrl+J

Comment: How would I know if a path is opened?

Comment: By eye, actually.. you see that shape has not one edge (it is visible only in outline mode).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with other CS6 compatible scripts:

[Select Open Paths](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1034937)

[Close All paths](http://www.williammpark.utvinternet.com/scripts.zip)

[Select Open Paths](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byo6fVktW-qEamQyZnNobjJIa1E/edit)

And this super nice one that lets you select open paths, gradients, transparencies, etc:

[Extended Select](http://www.aridocean.com/scripts_en.php)

Comment: Thanks for the links! A few are dead - you might wish to clean them up.

Comment: All working for me when re-checked 2014-11-24

Comment: Found this very helpful. there does not seem to be any built in function for selecting all open paths but the first link did the trick for me. great for post pathfinder slice cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I have a method for finding open paths. Using the document info objects, I go through the artwork and select certain pieces and when I find the piece i've selected that shows an open path, I copy that selection over so i can separate the section with the open path and that way it's easier to find. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you can't select the stroke alignment, it's usually because you or the person that created the object you're trying to outline, created a line segment instead of a complete or closed path. Using the pen tool, hover over the anchor points. When you mouse over the line between anchor points, you'll see a "+" sign, offering you the option to add an anchor point. Mouse over an anchor point and a minus sign should appear (option to delete anchor point) If you get a diagonal slash, however, you've found your problem. This indicates a line segment and not an anchor point. Simply hold the ctrl (command) key, deselect the object, then while still holding ctrl key, highlight the point that was found to be a line segment. Be careful to avoid selecting other points. Then, hit ctrl+J to join the points and close the path. Now you will be able to align the stroke anywhere you please.

So, the short answer is, you're not working on a closed path. Find the open segment, close the path and you're in business.